# Looping dates by month Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, datetime

I want to loop start date and end date and generate dates by month. I use this code:

```
<?php
    $start    = (new DateTime($cust_data->date_sold));
    $end      = (new DateTime($cust_data->due_date));
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
    $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    foreach ($period as $dt) {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$dt->format("m-d-Y")."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Example date:

```
$start = '02-05-2018'
$end = '08-05-2018'
```

Result:

```
02-05-2018

03-05-2018

04-05-2018

05-05-2018

06-05-2018

07-05-2018
```

I want it to be like this:

```
03-05-2018

04-05-2018

05-05-2018

06-05-2018

07-05-2018

08-05-2018
```

But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope This  will help you.

```
    $s1 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('02-05-2018' . ' + 1 day')); // Added one day to start from 03-05-2018
    $s2 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('08-05-2018'.' + 1 day')); //Added one day to end with 08-05-2018
    $start = new DateTime($s1);
    $end   = new DateTime($s2);
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
    $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
    foreach ($period as $dt) {
       echo "<pre>".$dt->format("d-m-Y");
    }
```

I have Added code as per d-m-y format. you can change as you needed.

Comment: Thank you very much! Big help :)

Answer (score 1):

An approach that uses only native `DateTime` tools without having to parse the date again.

```
$start = (new DateTime($cust_data->date_sold))->modify('+1 day');
$end = (new DateTime($cust_data->due_date))->modify('+1 day');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("d-m-Y") . '<br>';
}
```